# Generic operation on slice of Cow<str>

Tags: string, vector, rust

I'm trying to implement the following code, which removes the prefix from a slice of `Cow<str>`'s.

```
fn remove_prefix(v: &mut [Cow<str>], prefix: &str) {
    for t in v.iter_mut() {
        match *t {
            Borrowed(&s) => s = s.trim_left_matches(prefix),
            Owned(s) => s = s.trim_left_matches(prefix).to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I can't get this to compile - I've tried loads of combinations of `&`'s and `*`'s but to no avail.
2. Is there a better way to apply functions to a `Cow<str>` without having to `match` it to `Borrowed` and `Owned` every time. I mean it seems like I should just be able to do something like `*t = t.trim_left_matches(prefix)` and if `t` is a `Borrowed(str)` it leaves it as a `str` (since `trim_left_matches` allows that), and if it is an `Owned(String)` it leaves it as a `String`. Similarly for `replace()` it would realise it has to convert both to a `String` (since you can't use `replace()` on a `str`). Is something like that possible?

Comment: *I can't get this to compile* without saying what kind of compilation errors?

Comment: Because I've tried lots of variations and they give lots of different errors. Question would be about 10 times longer if I included them all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question #1 strongly implies how you think pattern matching and/or pointers work in Rust doesn't quite line up with how they actually work.  The following code compiles:

```rust
fn remove_prefix(v: &mut [Cow<str>], prefix: &str) {
    use std::borrow::Cow::*;
    for t in v.iter_mut() {
        match *t {
            Borrowed(ref mut s) => *s = s.trim_left_matches(prefix),
            Owned(ref mut s) => *s = s.trim_left_matches(prefix).to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

If your case, `Borrowed(&s)` is matched against `Borrowed(&str)`, meaning that `s` is of type `str`.  This is impossible: you *absolutely cannot* have a variable of a dynamically sized type.  It's also counter-productive.  Given that you want to *modify* `s`, binding to it by value won't help at all.

What you *want* is to modify the thing contained in the `Borrowed` variant.  This means you want a mutable pointer to that storage location.  Hence, `Borrowed(ref mut s)`: this is *not* destructuring the value inside the `Borrowed` at all.  Rather, it binds directly to the `&str`, meaning that `s` is of type `&mut &str`; a mutable pointer to a (pointer to a `str`).  In other words: a mutable pointer to a string slice.

At that point, mutating the contents of the `Borrowed` is done by re-assigning the value through the mutable pointer: `*s = ...`.

Finally, the exact same reasoning applies to the `Owned` case: you were trying to bind by-value, then mutate it, which cannot possibly do what you want.  Instead, bind by mutable pointer to the storage location, then re-assign it.

As for question #2... not really.  That would imply some kind of overloading, which Rust doesn't do (by deliberate choice).  If you are doing this *a lot*, you could write an extension trait that adds methods of interest to `Cow`.

Comment: *strongly implies you have a faulty mental model of how pattern matching* => while true, I am afraid this could be resented as "too aggressive"; I have no suggestion to make, unfortunately, however it might be worth rewording this sentence; after all, we do not wish to scare the OP away!

Comment: Nah he's totally right - my mental model was incomplete. I have read the docs but with rust it seems you have to fight the compiler in mortal combat to really learn it! Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do it.

```
fn remove_prefix(v: &mut [Cow<str>], prefix: &str) {
    for t in v.iter_mut() {
        match *t {
            Cow::Borrowed(ref mut s) => *s = s.trim_left_matches(prefix),
            Cow::Owned(ref mut s) => *s = s.trim_left_matches(prefix).to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

`ref mut s` means “take a mutable reference to the value and call it `s`” in a pattern. Thus you have `s` of type `&mut &str` or `&mut String`. You must then use `*s =`  in order to change what that mutable reference is pointing to (thus, change the string inside the `Cow`).